# What is queue lifetime in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm creating queues using MassTransit and Azure Service Bus as transport. I'm not asking about messages lifetime. I need to know when queue will be deleted if no one subscriber do not subscribe for this queue?

Comment: Well, at least Azure will never delete your queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue will never be automatically deleted. As long as you do not delete it and as long as your account is valid will be there waiting for messages.